# TFS possible to pre-parse a file when check in?

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm new to TFS, we have just started to use TFS to manage our T-SQL code.

I would like to know if it's possible to create a pre-parse script to be run automatically when checking in scripts, to also make additional changes to the file? Exchange tabs to spaces within the file for example.

I would also like to be able to insert the changeset id as a comment in the script that I'm checking in.
So is it possible to know the new changeset id in pre-state while checking in the file?

This script I would prefer to develop in C#

Comment: "I would also like to be able to insert the changeset id as a comment" - Why would you want to do that?

Comment: For Stored Procedures I would like to know which changeset version that is installed in the server.

Answer (score 1):

The feature that you're after is called "Keyword Expansion", it is not currently built-in to TFS.

For more history and discussion on the [lack of Keyword Expansion in TFS, see this blog post from Buck Hodges](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2007/07/07/keyword-expansion-in-tfs.aspx).

There are two ways to achieve what you're after:

1. Use a client-side TFS Check-in Policy. This is code that executes on your machine before the change is submitted to the server. [Here's an example](http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/).
2. Setup a Build server and a build script and enable 'Gated Checkins'. Then as part of the build script, make the additional changes to the file, before checking in.

There are a number of downsides with both of these approaches though:

- You can't predict or know the Changeset ID, until after it's actually been checked-in. So you would either have to leave this out, and settle with something like current date/time. Or you would have to get funky and check it in again, with the previous changeset number.
- With client-side TFS Check-in Policies, they have to be deployed to every user who wants to check-in. That is usually too much of an administrative burden, so people don't really use them.